# Integrating Laplace's equation over a sphere

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, integration, coulombs-law, dirac-delta-distributions

The Wikipedia page on [Laplace's equation states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_equation#Fundamental_solution) that

> if the Laplacian of $u$ is integrated over any volume that encloses the source point, 
>   $$\iiint_V \nabla \cdot \nabla u \, d^3V =-1.$$

I can't seem to find an explanation for this elsewhere, can someone explain why this is the case? And would this still apply if the sphere is in thermal equilibrium?

Comment: On the wikipedia page for what? This question is impossible to answer without context.

Comment: Page for Laplace's equation.

Comment: This is a pure mathematical result. It has nothing to do with thermal equilibrium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add context missing from the question, we consider a fundamental solution to the Laplace equation

$$\Delta u=-\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0).$$

The answer to the question then becomes very simple. Integrate both sides over a sphere containing the source point $\textbf{x}_0$ and recalling $\Delta u=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}u$, we have

$$\oint_V\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}u\,\mathrm{d}V=-1.$$